# redirect specific page to another specific page in iis web.config

Tags: redirect, web-config

We've moved our site from a php apache site to an asp.net mvc site and I'm trying to get specific redirects to work but am getting stuck.

Basically I want any request for http://www.mysite.com/index.php?pr=about_us to be redirected to http://www.mysite.com/About-Us

I've tried this but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="About Us" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="index.php?pr=About_Us" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.mysite.com/About-Us" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I've also tried this but it didn't work either.

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
    <add wildcard="index.php?pr=About_Us" destination="/About-Us" />
</httpRedirect>
```

I've got about a dozen of these specific redirects that I need to implement to various pages.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<rule name="About Us" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$">
        <conditions>
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="index.php?pr=About_Us" />
        </conditions>
    </match>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.mysite.com/About-Us" />
</rule>
```

**Edit**

This is another possibility for the conditions:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="?pr=About_Us" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="index.php" />
</conditions>
```

***Edit - Working Solution***

```
<rule name="About Us" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="/?pr=About_Us$" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="index.php" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.mysite.com/About-Us" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Where does this go in the web.config? Under the system.webserver section?